# What is the best way to display string items stored in Enumerable<string> object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may seem an easy question, but is there a best way in terms of the method or syntax for displaying items stored in an Enumerable object of type string in a TextBox? (and other controls)

I have the following code:

```
    if (CategoryTypes.Count() >= 1) 
    {
         foreach (var category in CategoryTypes)
         {
             txtCategories.Text += category + ", ";
         }
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Better way in what sense? Performance? Readability? Something else?

Comment: You can skip the if() clause. foreach () does that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
txtCategories.Text = string.Join<string>(", ", CategoryTypes);
```

Comment: +1 A benefit of this approach is that it also eliminates the trailing ", " that is caused by the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **CategoryTypes** is a string array. You could do

```
txtCategories.Text = string.Join(CategoryTypes, ", ");
```